# PHP strtotime for the closest day to the day after the 28th of the month

Tags: php, strtotime

Is there a way to determine if the 28th of the month has passed?

For example, if the day was the 29th of the janurary, how could I grab the 28th of janurary, or if the day was the first of janurary, how could I grab the 28th of December? Is there a way to one line this in php strtotime()?

Comment: better if you include your tried code?

Answer (score 0):

Does it *have* to be a one-liner? Does it *have* to use `strtotime()`?

```
$date = new DateTime('2014-01-01');
if ($date->format('j') < 28) {
    $date->modify('previous month');
}
$date->setDate($date->format('Y'), $date->format('n'), 28);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$curDay = date('d');
$curMonth = date('m');
$curYear = date('Y');

$thisMonth = $curYear.'-'.$curMonth.'-28';

if ($curDay > 28) {
    echo 'Last 28th was: '.$thisMonth;
}else{
    echo 'Last 28th was: '.date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-1 month',strtotime($thisMonth)));
}
```

Sorry this is nowhere near one line - if you were using the current date it could be done but looking for the 28th of the month means there is a bit more to do.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$d = '2014-07-29';
if (date('d', strtotime($d)) > 28) {
  $diff = date('d', strtotime($d)) - 28;
  echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($d.'-'.$diff.' day')); //2014-07-28 getting 1 day back date
}
```

Comment: But what if it is the 30th of the month?